# Running Shiny app through Python

Tags: python, r, shiny

I would like to ask if it's possible (and if somebody has done it so far) to open a R Shiny application through R?

My idea would be to create some GUI with links that open different R Shiny scripts and opens the application, but I'm not sure how would that happen or if it is even possible. One of the things I've found for executing R Scripts from Python is [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/integrating-python-and-r-part-ii-executing-r-from-python-and-vice-versa/).

If there is some other documentation (I could not find any so far) as well?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you mean *"to open a R Shiny application through **python**?*" Regardless, I think this question is better suited for [Software Recs](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), as suggesting software is [off-topic on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Oh okay, thank you for the recommendation! I'll close this question then here.